# bash scripting and conditional statements

Tags: bash

I am trying to run a simple bash script but I am struggling on how to incoperate a condition. any pointers. the loop says. I would like to incoperate a conditions such that when gdalinfo cannot open the image it copies that particular file to another location.

```
for file in `cat path.txt`; do gdalinfo $file;done
```

works fine in opening the images and also shows which ones cannot be opened.
the wrong code is

```
for file in `cat path.txt`; do gdalinfo $file && echo $file; else cp $file /data/temp
```

Comment: if your script gets too unweildy, you could consider using more than one line in a file

Comment: The chances are high that if the `gdalinfo` program can't open the file, you can't copy it.  It might depend on permissions; if the files are read-only and `gdalinfo` opens them for (reading and) writing, then you will probably be able to copy the files, change the permissions, and then operate on the copy.  Otherwise, though, if `gdalinfo` can't open it, there's a very high probability that copy can't either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can say:

```
for file in `cat path.txt`; do gdalinfo $file || cp $file /data/temp; done
```

This would copy the file to `/data/temp` if gdalinfo cannot open the image.

If you want to print the filename in addition to copying it in case of failure, say:

```
for file in `cat path.txt`; do gdalinfo $file || (echo $file && cp $file /data/temp); done
```

Answer (score 6):

Again, and again and again - zilion th again...

**Don't use contsructions** like

```
for file in `cat path.txt`
```

or

```
for file in `find .....`
for file in `any command what produces filenames`
```

Because the code will BREAK immediatelly, when the filename or path contains space. Never use it for any command what produces filenames. Bad practice. Very Bad. It is incorrect, mistaken, erroneous, inaccurate, inexact, imprecise, faulty, WRONG.

The correct form is:

```
for file in some/*   #if want/can use filenames directly from the filesystem
```

or

```
find . -print0 | while IFS= read -r -d '' file
```

or (if you sure than no filename contains a newline) can use

```
cat path.txt | while read -r file
```

but here the `cat` is useless, (really - command what *only* copies a file to STDOUT **is** useless). You should use instead

```
while read -r file
do
   #whatever
done < path.txt
```

It is faster (doesn't fork a new process, as do in case of *every* pipe).

The above `while`s will fill the corect filename into the variable `file` in cases when the filename contains a space too. The `for` **will not**. Period. Uff. Omg.

And use `"$variable_with_filename"` instead of pure `$variable_with_filename` for the same reason. If the filename contains a white-space any command will misunderstand it as two filenames. This probably not, what you want too..

So, enclose any shell variable what contain a filename with double quotes. (not only filename, but anything what can contain a space). `"$variable"` is correct.

If i understand right, you want copy files to `/data/temp` when the `gdalinfo` returns error.

```
while read -r file
do
   gdalinfo "$file" || cp "$file" /data/temp
done < path.txt
```

Nice, short and safe (at least if your path.txt really contains one filename per line).

And maybe, you want use your script more times, therefore dont out the filename inside, but save the script in a form

```
while read -r file
do
   gdalinfo "$file" || cp "$file" /data/temp
done
```

and use it like:

```
mygdalinfo < path.txt
```

more universal...

and maybe, you want only show the filenames for what `gdalinfo` returns error

```
while read -r file
do
   gdalinfo "$file" || printf "$file\n"
done
```

and if you change the `printf "$file\n"` to `printf "$file\0"` you can use the script in a pipe safely, so:

```
while read -r file
do
   gdalinfo "$file" || printf "$file\0"
done
```

and use it for example as:

```
 mygdalinfo < path.txt | xargs -0 -J% mv % /tmp/somewhere
```

Howgh.

Comment: `xargs -J` ?? did you mean `-I`?

Comment: @glennjackman not really... ;) mean -J want replace many args but only in the 1st occurence... test it with e.g.: `seq 10 | xargs -J% echo % /some/where` and imagine the `mv` instead of `echo` ;) E.g. want move _many_ files into `/some/where` in one `mv` pass

Comment: Ah wait, you're on a BSD-ish system ([xargs(1)](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=xargs)). GNU [xargs](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man1/xargs.1.html) uses `-I` for the same purpose.

Comment: The GNU [mv](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man1/mv.1.html) command lets you write `xargs -0 mv -t /tmp/somewhere` and let all the filenames follow.